# Add autocomplete to the navigation bar in Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm running a Rails project which consists of Navgation bar on all the pages. I also have a input tag on the nav bar for searching purpose, but how to implement autocomplete in the particular search bar.

I tried using rails-jquery-autocomplete and implemented the way it asked but unfortunately it didn't worked for me. No search result are visible on screen or on console

brands_controller.rb

```
class Admin::BrandsController < Admin::AdminController
  autocomplete :brand, :name
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :brands, param: :uuid do
  get :autocomplete_brand_name, :on => :collection
end
```

_navigationbar.html.erb

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-left" role="search">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control search-bar" placeholder="Type here for search..." data-autocomplete="<%=autocomplete_brand_name_admin_brands_path%>">
   </div>
</form>
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require moltran/modernizr.min
//= require moltran/bootstrap.min
//= require tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput.min.js
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control search-bar" placeholder="Type here for search..." data-autocomplete="/admin/brands/autocomplete_brand_name">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Dinesh I have updated the code. 
Please check it

Comment: Can you post your gemfile and application.js

Comment: @Dinesh done please look into it

Comment: Where is your js such as, 
`$( ".search-bar" ).autocomplete({
  appendTo: "#someElem"
});`

Comment: @Sarvan I haven't added any of such line. As in this is a gem so it handles everything. Main issue over here is that after entering text no request is passed onto my console

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete` in application.js. Update application.js to

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require moltran/modernizr.min
//= require moltran/bootstrap.min
//= require tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput.min.js
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

In your gemfile add

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Also replace input tag with

```
<%=autocomplete_field_tag 'search', '', autocomplete_brand_name_admin_brands_path %>
```

Comment: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/autocomplete' with type 'application/javascript'

Comment: Rails 5.0.0.1 is the version

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi In your gemfile add `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` then do `bundle install` and restart server.

Comment: I just did that only.. I restarted the server.. The error has vanished.. But still I cannot view any brand name in my search box... No autocomplete logs on the console also

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi What is the generated html for input ?

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi What do you see in Network Tab in Developer console when you type in your input text?

Comment: Sorry @Dinesh couldn't get you.. I'm running the server locally using passenger, on that while I fire my request no logs are displayed or request is fired

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126191/discussion-between-syed-asad-abbas-zaidi-and-dinesh).